# m2Eclips Integration Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I was configuring Eclips(Helios) for web development,initially

1) I installed subclips through Help->Install Software->paste link of the  update site. (Successful)

2) I downloaded and installed maven,configured environment variables through windows  and   checked through command prompt.(Works fine : shows all the version details and system details)

3)Now i am installing m2Eclipse by Help->Install software->paste link in the dialog box.(Error: Not able to find additional dependence)

I have already installed Eclipse Kepler version and its working fine. But if i want to uses Helios my eclipse  in not getting configured for maven (m2Eclipse) integration.

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: are you sure that that's the error your getting? google is coming up with nothing

Comment: Do you absolutely need Helios? Why not just use a web version of Kepler or even Juno?

Comment: Error Message: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Missing requirement: Maven POM XML Editor 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse

Comment: Problem Solved:1. Goto :
Help -> Install New Software
2. Add following URL in "Work with:"

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0

Comment: Then answer your own question and get it over with :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Goto : Help -> Install New Software 2. Add following URL in "Work with:" download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0